# Getting a Dev-C++ built program to output UNICODE characters to the Windows command line

Tags: c, unicode, command-line, dev-c++

If you can answer any of my questions, that would be awesome.

Here's the scoop: I'm teaching an intro to programming class in Thailand to 11th graders. It's been going great so far, their level of English is high enough that I can teach in English and have them write programs in English and everything is fine and dandy.

However, as speakers of a language with non-Latin characters, I feel that they should at least learn what UNICODE is. I won't test them on it or bog them down with implementation details, but I want to show them an example of a UNICODE program that can do I/O with Thai characters.

I'm operating under the following constraints, none of which can be changed (at least for this semester):

- The program must run on Windows 7
- The program must be in C (not C++)
- We must use Dev-C++ (v. 4.9.9.3) as our IDE (I'm going to try and convince the admins to change for next semester, but they may not want to)
- The program should output to the Command Line (I'd like it to "look like" the programs we've been writing so far)
- I want it to be easy to set up and run, though I'm not opposed to including a Batch file to do some setup work for the kids.

Here's how far I've gotten, and the questions I have:

- In Control Panel > Regions > Administrative > Language for non-UNICODE programs is set to Thai.
- I used "chcp 874" to set the [Thai codepage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305142.aspx) in the Command Line, but characters from the keyboard come appear as garbage characters. Is this maybe because the keyboard mappings are wrong or do I have to change something else?
- I wrote a program with the line: printf("\u0E01\n"); which prints ก, the first letter in the Thai alphabet. Is that the right syntax?
- I received a compiler warning that "Universal Characters are only supported in C++ and C99." Does Dev-C++ not compile to C99? Is there a way I could get a C99 compiler for it?
- I ran the code and got garbage characters. I imagine this could be because of the compiler, the command line, or any number of other things.

I'd love to end this course with a program that outputs สวัสดีโลก, the Thai equivalent of "Hello World!" I've done tons of googling, but every answer I've found either doesn't work in this specific case or involved a different IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's my bit of help. I don't use Dev-C++ as my IDE, so I can't help you with IDE specific things, but the following is standard to most C/C++ compilers:

`wprintf` is the `printf` implementation for wide characters (unicode).

When using wide characters you will use `wchar_t` in place of `char` for defining strings.

so you might do something like this

```
#include <wchar.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    wchar_t* str = L"สวัสดีโลก";
    wprintf(L"%s", str);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

`wprintf` is most likely what you're looking for.

Other functions for printing and manipulating wide strings can be found by researching the `wchar.h` header file.

Reference:
[wprintf - C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wprintf/)

Using L before the quotations means you intend to define a wide string. (unicode)

Hope that helps,

-Dave

Comment: I changed to wide characters and took Ahmed's advice about wide characters. It still doesn't render properly to cmd, but I piped the output to a text file and it rendered properly there, so the output is definitely correct now. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to change the font of the command prompt to one that supports unicode characters as I don't think the Terminal font supports them. You're most welcome, I hope your class works out well for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used DEV-C++ IDE :-) However, after reading up on it a bit I see that 
dev-c++ version 4.9.9.3 uses gcc-3.5.4 mingw port.  Which has universal character support status of "Done" see http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.4/c99status.html for details. You have to change the IDE configuration such that the compiler uses -std=c99 as part of the compiler flags.

Hopefully that will do the trick.

I will try to fiddle with it on my own system and see how far we can get. Will update the answer if I find more clues :-)

Comment: I set that flag and took Dave's advice about wide characters. It still doesn't render properly to cmd, but I piped the output to a text file and it rendered properly there, so the output is definitely correct now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the **code page** in a console C program, you can add the header `<stdlib.h>` and the line `system("CHCP 874");` at the beginning of the program.

If you need a free compiler conforming with C99 under windows, you can try **Pelles C**:

http://www.christian-heffner.de/index.php?page=download&lang=en

It is conforming at all with C99.

You have to use wide-string constants, that have the following syntax:

```
L"Wide string\n"
```

Instead of printf(), you need to use wprintf() and the like.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/wchar.h.html